# What syntax does PG want me to use?

Tags: postgresql

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE textcol NOT IN $1;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
```

`$1` is sent as an array of strings from the application. Parameterized query. pglib. PHP.

Comment: If `$1` is really an array, try `where textcol <> ALL ($1)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your PHP lib handles arrays, but the [correct Pg syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) for `IN` certainly requires parentheses.

You probably want the query to look more like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE textcol NOT IN ($1);
```